# Table view in segmented control doesn’t show data immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got a table view under a segmented control, the table view's data is retrieved from Firebase database, here is the code:

```
func retrieveParticipatedData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let storyIDRef = DBRef.child("Story IDs").child(userID!)
    var participatedStoryItems: [ParticipatedStoriesPageData] = []

    storyIDRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : String] {

            for (_, value) in dict {

                self.DBRef.child("To be reviewed stories").child(value).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                    if let storyDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

                        let storyTitle = storyDict["Book Title"] as? String
                        let storyDescription = storyDict["Description"] as? String
                        let storyID = value
                        let votes = storyDict["Votes"] as? Int

                        let story = ParticipatedStoriesPageData(storyKey: storyID, storyTitle: storyTitle!, storyDescription: storyDescription!, votes: votes!)
                        participatedStoryItems.append(story)
                    }
                    self.participatedStories = participatedStoryItems
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    retrieveParticipatedData { (isRetreived) in

        if isRetreived {
            self.tableView.isHidden = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }   
    }
}
```

There is no issue with the retrieval of the data. The table view and the segmented control is initially hidden and once the data is retrieved, I unhide them.

The problem is that the data in the table view isn't displayed immediately, I have to go to the other tab and come back (I've got 2 tabs in my segmented control), only then the data is displayed in the table view. I have also added a picture of the database.

[image: Database]

[image: Participants database]

### Update

Here is what I tried with Matt's help:

```
func retrieveParticipatedData() {

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let storyIDRef = DBRef.child("Story IDs").child(userID!)
    var participatedStoryItems: [ParticipatedStoriesPageData] = []

    storyIDRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : String] {
            for (_, value) in dict {
                self.DBRef.child("To be reviewed stories").child(value).child("Participants").child("Chapter 1 Author").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

                    if snapshot.value as? String == self.userID {
                        dispatchGroup.enter()

                        self.DBRef.child("To be reviewed stories").child(value).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                            if let storyDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

                                let storyTitle = storyDict["Book Title"] as? String
                                let storyDescription = storyDict["Description"] as? String
                                let storyID = value
                                let votes = storyDict["Votes"] as? Int

                                let story = ParticipatedStoriesPageData(storyKey: storyID, storyTitle: storyTitle!, storyDescription: storyDescription!, votes: votes!)
                                participatedStoryItems.append(story)
                            }
                            self.participatedStories = participatedStoryItems.reversed()
                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                        }
                        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                            print("Retrieved")
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                        // It works if I do this
                        /*dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                            print("Retrieved")
                            self.setupTableView // Creates the table view
                        }*/
                        //But I don't wanna do this cuz then there would be no table view if there is no data retreived.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    retrieveParticipatedData()
    setupStackView()
    setupTableView()  // Creates the table view
}
```

Comment: Hey i think the problem is that the completion takes place when after the first iteration of the loop, is there any way I could call the completion after the loop is completed?

Comment: Also the first key/value in the storyIDs node (-1 = "8055") is just dummy data, the actual data is after the that

Comment: To call the completion after a loop of asynchronous calls, use a DispatchGroup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004414/swift-4-completion-handler-for-loop-not-working

Comment: Also you are calling `completion(true)` way too early and way too many times 

Comment: No luck with that either :(

Comment: I’d need to see the new code. I feel confident you’re on the right track.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Your `dispatchGroup.enter()` is in the wrong place. Copy the models exactly.

Comment: Yeah I tried it in different positions, but its not working

Comment: currently you are reloading the tableView when all of data is appended to the datasource, but i would recommened you to reload the tableView after the append statment, it will show the data instantly

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed Hey that didn't work :/

Comment: How bad do you want to keep the table hidden until all the data is loaded? it simplifies things a lot if you drop that requirement

Comment: @Rob.R have you tried creating a segmented table? Table.reloadData() doesn’t work for some reason, this is why I have to wait for everything to load

Comment: yes I have 2 in one of my apps with table views. one of the segments populates an array from firebase and displays it in the table view.  .reloadData() works fine on my end and its about 10 lines of code.  I'm assuming that you're calling it when the segmented controller is pressed which is why your data appears when you switch segments. is that correct?

Comment: Umm yeah you are correct, the data appears once I switch segments, but I’m also calling .reloadData after retrieving data too

Comment: When it’s a just a table view, it works fine but when it’s a segmented table view, I get this problem

Comment: I can see no error handling.. could it be so that some of the data fetching fails? Completion blocks are only called for success paths, and in the case with dispatchgroup, calls to `enter` and `leave` may not be balanced if there were any errors. Didn't use firebase myself, but it seems like there's a way to handle errors: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

Humor me and try this.  Don't hide your table view and just call this func in your viewDidLoad().  For my app I'm downloading a long list of users and loading profile photos's async as well with a segmented controller.  I could be wrong here since I can't test it against firebase but this is similar to what I'm doing.

```
    func retrieveParticipatedData() {

    let storyIDRef = DBRef.child("Story IDs").child(userID!)
    var participatedStoryItems: [ParticipatedStoriesPageData] = []

    storyIDRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : String] {

            for (_, value) in dict {

                self.DBRef.child("To be reviewed stories").child(value).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                    if let storyDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

                        let storyTitle = storyDict["Book Title"] as? String
                        let storyDescription = storyDict["Description"] as? String
                        let storyID = value
                        let votes = storyDict["Votes"] as? Int

                        let story = ParticipatedStoriesPageData(storyKey: storyID, storyTitle: storyTitle!, storyDescription: storyDescription!, votes: votes!)
                        participatedStoryItems.append(story)
                    }
                    self.participatedStories = participatedStoryItems // should this be "append()" instead of "="? if not why not just call self.participatedStories.append(story) above instead?
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, just like how it used to bn :/